# Is this syntax for the TSQL Where clause 'Search Condition' incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Shouldn't something like:

```
WHERE 1=2 and 2=3, 1=1
```

be possible with this syntax?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx

```
    <search_condition> ::= 
    { [ NOT ] <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } 
    [ { AND | OR } [ NOT ] { <predicate> | ( <search_condition> ) } ] 
[ ,...n ] 
<predicate> ::= 
    { expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } expression 
    | string_expression [ NOT ] LIKE string_expression 
  [ ESCAPE 'escape_character' ] 
    | expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN expression AND expression 
    | expression IS [ NOT ] NULL 
    | CONTAINS 
  ( { column | * } , '<contains_search_condition>' ) 
    | FREETEXT ( { column | * } , 'freetext_string' ) 
    | expression [ NOT ] IN ( subquery | expression [ ,...n ] ) 
    | expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } 
  { ALL | SOME | ANY} ( subquery ) 
    | EXISTS ( subquery )     }
```

Edit:
This `WHERE 1=2 and 2=3, 1=1` should have been `WHERE 1=2 and 2=3, and 1=1`.
Thanks lad2025 for the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not allowed. See human readable diagrams:

**Search Conditions**

[image]

**Predicate**
[image]

According to [Syntax Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx):

> **[,...n]**
>
> Indicates the preceding item can be repeated n number of times. The
>   occurrences are separated by commas.
>
> **[...n]**
>
> Indicates the preceding item can be repeated n number of times. The
>   occurrences are separated by blanks.

In my opinion there should be `[...n]`, the commas are not allowed like:

```
SELECT '1' AS val
WHERE 1=2 AND 2=2,AND 3=3
```

generate:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: So if this `WHERE 1=2 and 2=3, 1=1` is not allowed is this `[ ,...n ] ` part of the specification incorrect?

Comment: @FooUser I don't know exactly BNF MS Syntax, but based on diagrams I think you can misunderstand `,`. It is rather for multiple occurences not for `,` itself

Comment: I believe that's correct, @FooUser. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx), `[,...n]` indicates an allowance for multiple occurrences separated by commas whereas `[...n]` indicates an allowance for multiple occurrences separated by spaces. The latter is probably what ought to be there.

Comment: @lad2025 [ ,...] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx seems to be for multiple occurrences separated by commas.

Comment: @JoeFarell it would seem that way since I can not get a where clause with a comma to compile...

Comment: @FooUser It seems there is bug in documentation and it should be [...n]

Comment: Thanks, I'm writing an SQL emitter, this caught my eye, so will pretend like [ ,...n] is [ ...n].